# different routes when boolean is true in rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my routes.rb

```
Devel::Application.routes.draw do
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index', as: :authenticated_user
  end
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  resources :users
end
```

My user table has a column `:admin => true/false`. How could I check and `root :to` a different controller, when the flag is true.

Only thing i know is that I can handle it in the views with `if current_user.admin?`.

Any suggestion or ideas?

best regards
denym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply redirect the user to the admin page inside of the `home#index` action, after you've determined that they are an admin. Make sure that said page is access restricted, however, just in case someone goes there manually, or gets redirected on accident.

I don't think it's appropriate to change the home page conditionally in the routes file at all.

Also, I believe that the `routes.rb` file is loaded just once, upon the application starting, so I'm not sure that any conditional logic would be effective anyway.

Comment: `before_filter :authorize_admin, only: :index
  def authorize_admin
    redirect_to '/admin/index' if current_user.admin?
    #redirects to admin controller if admin? true 
  end`
Did this in my home_controller, only annoying thing is the redirect_to syntax.

Comment: But this means to handle user permissions by Pages for each permission. And the rules might be more complex than just "user". "moderator", "admin".

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup, wrote my own with warden...

in your application_controller.rb
write something like

```
def authorize_admin
redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Access Denied' if current_user.admin == false
end
```

or whatever name you have for admin/user, just as long as its a boolean on your user.

then in your pages_controller.rb
then scope out as needed, if you want to deny all access just do a

```
before_action :authorize_admin
```

otherwise nest it under any def you like...

```
def action
authorize_admin
blah blah blah
end
```